Coefficients of the characteristic polynomial and positive definite matrices
I revisited my old notes and saw that my former tutor once told us in Linear Algebra that if we want to check if a matrix $\bf A$ is positive definite, then we can check the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial:
$$
{\bf A}\ \mbox{is}\ positive\ definite\ \Leftrightarrow\forall\ 0 \leq i \leq n-1\
\mbox{it holds that}\ (-1)^ia_i > 0
$$
with $a_i$ being the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial $\chi_{\bf A} (X) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_iX^i$.
Is that true?
If so, why is it true?
I don't need a proof but maybe a theorem or even an intuitive explanation, if possible.
Answers are appreciated!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs#Negative_roots

Positive (semi) definiteness is defined for both symmetric and non-symmetric matrices. However, it is usually considered for symmetric matrices. I assume $A$ is a real symmetric matrix. Here, $A$ is positive definite if and only if all eigenvalues of $A$ are strictly greater than zero. Note that for symmetric matrices all eigenvalues are real.
Therefore, $A$ is positive definite if and only if all roots of $\chi_A$ are strictly greater than zero.
What you wrote is not precise; it seems you consider $a_n=1$. You should say the roots of $\chi_A(X)=X^n +\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_iX^i$ are strictly greater than zero if and only if $(-1)^{i}a_{n-i}>0$ for $1\le i \le n$.
It is important to note that it is not true in general. That is, for arbitrary polynomial $p(X)=X^n +\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_iX^i$, the condition $(-1)^{i}a_{n-i}>0$ for $1\le i \le n$ is necessary for $p(X)$ to have only positive roots. In our case, this necessary condition becomes the necessary and sufficient condition because $\chi_A(X)$ has a particular structure that all of its roots are real.
The most complete criterion that tells you for arbitrary polynomial $P(X)$ with real coefficients how many roots have negative real-part, how many have positive real-part, and how many are pure imaginary is the Ruth-Hurwitz criterion. In your case, that all of the roots are real, you can check Descartes' rule of signs as mentioned in the comment.
